# Where OpenShift Container Platform store image before pushing to external repository

Tags: docker, openshift, nexus

I want to push a docker image to nexus after built on OCP. This is what I use

```html
output:
    to:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: 'nexus.compnanyhost/image:latest'
```

and it returns

```html
error pinging docker registry nexus.compnanyhost/image:latest
```

I can't open a full range of ports so I need to know precisely where the store image is before pushing to the external repository and maybe how to find the port that OCP ping to nexus

Answer (score 0):

The docker image is pushed from the node where the build is running.
You can put a specific node-selector on buildconfig to ensure the source ip is always the same.

pm

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the information, do you know what port the worker node use to send requests?